# Linear Regression in MATLAB without fitlm

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I am tasked to perform a prediction analysis. This requires performing a linear regression on several (~10) predictor variables and coming up with intercepts for all and a constant.
so final equation will be of this format `y = c + c1x1 + c2x2 + c3x3....`

Now I know that you can use `fitlm` function in MATLAB that is available with Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox however at this point I don't know if we will be purchasing it. How do I perform linear regression on them ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the closed form solution of linear least squares.

C=inv(transpose(X)*X)*transpose(X)*y

In the above, make the first row of X all ones, and the following rows are x1, x2,...

C will contain the corresponding constants. The first entry in C is c.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html

You can write your predictor variables as a matrix X using `X = [ones(length(x1),1),x1,x2,x3,...,xn]` and formulating the response variables Y as the equation Y = XB and doing a matrix inverse operation using mldivide as `B = X\Y` to find your regression coefficients.